# What is the consequence of not using a key with google ajax api load

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I can call the google api this way with a key :

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAA1XbMiDxx_BTCY2_FkPh06RRaGTYH6UMl8mADNa0YKuWNNa8VNxQEerTAUcfkyrr6OwBovxn7TDAH5Q"></script>
```

But i can also omit to specify a key like this:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

and my code still work.

What would be the consequence of not using a key ? Could Google block my requests ? Would it be a good idea to use Production code that call Google api for a intranet app ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, key is used only for some APIs, like Google Maps, and ignored for, for example, jquery hosted on Google CDN.

Answer (score 0):

It might work for a small number of requests while you're testing out your site, but then stop working once you start getting traffic.  Don't risk showing your users a broken page with missing content!

Answer (score 0):

I think they've recently disabled the no-api working with jQuery does this still work for you?